# how to get custom attribute data in product afterGetPrice in cart page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

in cart page i want to display custom msrp price for non loggedin user when i get custommsrp in afterGetPrice function for one item will return correctly but for other items display 0.00